# SQL UPDATE multiple rows of matching data between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to `UPDATE` MySQL ***Table1*** with ***Table2*** data with column `CODE` being the unique id between tables.

**Table1**

| CODE | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 15 |
| C | 20 |

**Table2**

| CODE | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| B | 10 |
| C | 5 |

Desired output is ***Table1*** `QTY` data is added on (not replaced) with ***Table2*** `QTY` for matching codes between the two tables.

I have tried below, however does not give the expected result and throws me a syntax error.

```
UPDATE Table1 set QTY=(QTY +
SELECT IF(QTY IS NULL or QTY = '', '0', QTY) 
from Table2)
```

Obviously my knowledge is limited on SQL as I'm still learning, appreciate if someone can please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`.  I would recommend aggregating before joining:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select t2.code, sum(t2.qty) as qty
        from table2 t2
        group by t2.code
       ) t2
       using (code)
    set t1.qty = t2.qty + t1.qty;
```

Aggregating first ensures that you get the results you expect if multiple rows in `table2` have the same code.  If you *know* the codes are unique in `table2`, you can just use a `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       using (code)
    set t1.qty = t2.qty + t1.qty;
```